# Uncaught ReferenceError: displayAddr is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

getting this error, cant tell why, tried moving the script declarations to body but getting the same error.

The map is loaded succesfully so the jquery function is ready.
any suggestions?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src = "jquery-1.10.2.js" > </script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src = "gmap3.js" > </script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id= "h1">  
            <h1 id="mapsDemo">Maps Demo</h1>
        </div>
        <form id="formAddress"> 
            address: <input id="addressBox" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter location">
            <button  type="button" onclick="displayAddr()">Find</button> 
        </form>
        <div id="map">
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#map").width("600px").height("350px").gmap3();

                function displayAddr(){
                    $inputAddress = $("#addressBox").val();
                    console.log($inputAddress);
                }
            });         
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define a function inside scope of another function, you can only use it inside that function's scope. If you want use a function in inline event listeners, you should define it out of `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` , so you should change your code to this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src = "jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src = "gmap3.js" > </script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id= "h1">  
            <h1 id="mapsDemo">Maps Demo</h1>
        </div>
        <form id="formAddress"> 
            address: <input id="addressBox" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter location">
            <button  type="button" onclick="displayAddr()">Find</button> 
        </form>
        <div id="map">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function displayAddr(){
                $inputAddress = $("#addressBox").val();
                console.log($inputAddress);
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#map").width("600px").height("350px").gmap3();
            });         
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```